# Having trouble submitting form and calling queued events after asynchronous event

Tags: jquery, preventdefault, stoppropagation, jquery-1.3

I have this working on local setup (with jquery.1.6.4) but it is not working on dev setup (jquery.1.3.2).

Consider the following form -

```
<form onsubmit="return validateMacros();">
     <input id="formsubmitbutton" type="submit" name="formsubmitbutton" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Note the `validateMacros();` call above.

And the following javascript -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function()
{

$("input#formsubmitbutton").click(preValidateUrls); 

        function preValidateUrls(evt)
        {
                evt.preventDefault(); //to prevent form submission until completion of async event

                $.ajax({
                    ...
                    ...
                    success: function(res)
                    {
                         $("form#frmBanners").submit();  //This submits the form in case of both versions but in 1.3.2 case, the validateMacros() function is not called
                    }
               });
       }

});

function validateMacros()
{
   //some logic here - which is not executing in case of jquery.1.3.2
}
```

When jquery.1.6.4 is loaded, the function `validateMacros()` executes after the completion of execution of `preValidateUrls()`, which is desired.

But when jquery.1.3.2 is loaded, `validateMacros()` does not execute at all and the form just submits.

How do I make it working on both the versions. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go unobtrusive!

```
$('form#frmBanners').on('submit', validateMacros);
```

What we're doing here is **subscribing** the function to the `submit` event of the form, after you give it an id (I just noticed you used `frmBanners` as an example). Unobstrusive means you're not putting any Javascript in your HTML, which is the primary purpose of libraries like jQuery. So, anywhere in your external Javascript file, include the line I provided above. Any time the form is *submitted* and **not** just when the submit button is clicked, the function will be called.

So, when you call `$("form#frmBanners").submit();`, the event is fired and the function is called. This is a step closer to following convention as far as firing these kinds of events go.

Comment: Also, why would you load the older version of jQuery? Just load the latest one.

Comment: could you please elaborate your answer. And we are not in position right now to upgrade to 1.3.2 on production, so need to make it work :(.

Comment: That worked. Thanks. But jquery `.on()` is supported version 1.7 onwards. I had to do `$('form#frmBanners').submit(function() { return validateMacros(this); );` for that.